# nginx only serve jpeg files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx

Hey I have a strange problem.

I created a really simple and basic site, without any CMS, using vanilla PHP sometimes in the page to show the date or include the menu.

The problem is that no assets can be loaded except for **jpg** files. All my CSS, JS and png are 404'd, while all subdirectories are 403 forbidden. I already changed access rules to 777, didnt change a thing.

For example, `subdomain.site.com/images/` is 403, but `subdomain.site.com/images/bg.jpg` is correctly found, while `subdomain.site.com/images/logo.png` just 404.

The server is running on nginx, but .htaccess files are working (I'm not a pro with servers, but at least "deny from all" works, so I guess all the rest works too). There's no way I can access nginx configuration.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: nginx doesn't use .htaccess, are you sure your server is nginx ? Also, i would suggest to add `nginx` tag to the question.

Comment: I have added the nginx tag for you, @solarBanana. As mentioned, you can't be running on nginx if you are using `.htaccess` - alternatively, you are running on nginx, but erroneously assuming that `.htaccess` actually works. Unless you have some sort of module for that (we would love to know about it). (And, your title says Apache, not nginx...)

Comment: The problem is that when I see a 404 error, it's clearly writen nginx under it. To verifiy if my htaccess file was being correctly interpreted, I put one with "deny from all" in the root directory, which was clearly accessible before. Then it became 403 forbidden...

Comment: In that case, you're probably using nginx as a reverse proxy to apache.You have to post here your full nginx.conf and your server/location blocks for your domain, in order to get any help.

Answer (score 0):

nginx can be configured to only respond to requests matching a predefined pattern, far easier than with Apache.

**Configuration (nginx):**

```
server {
    ...
    location /images {
        autoindex off;
        location ^/images/.+\.jpg$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
        }
        return 404;
    }
    ...
```

In this example, `/images/img.jpg` can be served but `/images/img.png` will be 404.

Unless you manage the server configuration, you cannot change that. Ask the server admin to do that. (Or change the configuration files if you can)